# How to know if a completion packet is for WSASend() or WSARecv() or AcceptEx()?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, iocp

When I call `WSASend()` or `WSARecv()` or `AcceptEx()`, a completion packet will be placed in the completion port and I can dequeue it using `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`. But how can I know what operation this completion packet represents?

Comment: Compare `LPOVERLAPPED` pointer you got from `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` with the pointer you passed to `WSASend` et al. You can also add additional members at the end of the structure, to stash extra information.

Comment: So I can add a `char` member to the end of the structure that will hold what type of operation this was, for example: 'S', 'R', 'A'? (this seems a better alternative than comparing pointers!)

Comment: @user4592590: yes, exactly. Raymond Chen described that feature on his blog: [The OVERLAPPED associated with asynchronous I/O is passed by address, and you can take advantage of that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/17/10106259.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an 'extended' `OVERLAPPED` structure which contains other information. Often this also contains the data buffer and some flags which tell the caller of `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` what the completion type is.

There are lots of useful tutorials about IOCP on the web and I expect all of them explain this as it's fairly fundamental. My tutorials can be found [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html), along with some code which implements a some simple IOCP servers.